# Problems using pivot_table on my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pivot my dataframe so I can make a document matrix but I am running into some errors with I try to pivot my dataframe. Here is my original dataframe before I try to mess with it.

```
tidy_filter1 = pd.DataFrame(df_tweetText["text"].str.split(expand = True).stack().reset_index())
tidy_filter = pd.DataFrame(tidy_filter1,index = tidy_format1["id"])
tidy_filter = tidy_filter1.rename(index = tidy_filter["id"], columns = {"level_1": "num",0:"word"})
tidy_filter1["level_1"] = tidy_filter1.groupby("id").cumcount()
tidy_filter = tidy_filter.drop(columns = ["id"])
tidy_filter = tidy_filter.rename(index = tidy_format1["id"])

id                    num    word
1104159474368024599    0    repmiketurner
1104159474368024599    1    time
1104159474368024599    2    michael
1104159474368024599    3    cohen
1104159474368024599    4    told
1104159474368024599    5    truth
1104159474368024599    6    pled
1104159474368024599    7    guilty
1104159474368024599    8    also
1104159474368024599    9    said
1104159474368024599    10    collusion
```

Now when I try to run this code below is where it breaks.

```
df_freq = tidy_filter.pivot_table(values='word', index=tidy_filter.index, columns='word', aggfunc=pd.Series.count)
```

The error gives me *KeyError: 'word'* which I don't understand. I tried to replace the values/columns with *tidy_filter['word]* but that did not work.

**Edit: I am looking for this output

```
id                   repmiketurner michael cohen told truth pled guilty also said collusion
1104159474368024599         1         1       1     1   1     1     1      1   1       1
1104155456019357703        0          0       0     1   1     0     0      1   0       0
```

**Edit2: I so when I type in tidy_filter['word'] it gives me a different KeyError: 'repmiketurner'

Comment: What is your expected output  ?

Comment: why are your `values` and `columns` pointing to the same field?

Comment: @Wen-Ben I just made an edit with desired output. Basically for every tweet(id) I want to show the number of occurrences a word has

Comment: @AlexS1 I just updated my question with a sample output. I the reason why I use words twice is I want for each tweet to give me a number of word occurances in each tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `pivot_table` command had to be changed - you had the arguments for `columns` and `values` interchanged. You just needed to use `columns='word'` and `values='num'`.

This is what worked for me

```
df_freq = tidy_filter.pivot_table(columns='word',
                                    index=tidy_filter.index,
                                    values='num',
                                    aggfunc=pd.Series.count)

# Put pivot table columns in order of unique values of the 'word' column
word_unique = tidy_filter['word'].unique().tolist()
df_freq = df_freq[word_unique]

print(df_freq)
word                 repmiketurner  time  michael  cohen  told  truth  pled  guilty  also  said  collusion
id                                                                                                        
1104159474368024599              1     1        1      1     1      1     1       1     1     1          1
```

Comment: That was perfect! Those bits gave me the desired output! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `pd.crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.id,df.word)
```

Comment: So I have crosstab a shot and it does work, but I might have too many tweets because my document matrix is very large and messy to look at.